# Изменение порядка отображения записей

Tags: php, битрикс

Пример кода ниже выводит записи из базы *bitrix* на страничку, но выводит их в порядке "От старой даты к новой" (поле `DATE_ACTIVE_FROM`).

Как изменить вывод в порядок "От новой даты к старой"?

```
 <?if( !empty($arItem["VIEW"]) ):?>
            <ul class="short-news">
                <?foreach ($arItem["VIEW"] as $key => $value):?>
                    <li>
                        <? $date = explode(" ", $value['DATE_ACTIVE_FROM']); ?>
                        <? $date[0] = str_replace('/','.',$date[0]); ?>
                        <span class="sn-date"><?=$date[0]?></span>
                        <noindex><a target="_blank" class="exp-news-name" rel="nofollow" href="<?=$value['PROPERTY_LINK_VALUE']?>"><?=$value['NAME']?></a></noindex>
                        <span class="clear"></span>
                    </li>
                <?endforeach;?>
            </ul>
        <?endif;?>
```

Comment: надо найти где он генерит данные и поменять сортировку.

Comment: Если выводите с помощью компонента, то в его настройках есть опциях как сортировать по возрастанию или по убыванию. Если самописно выбираете из базы, то там тоже можно задать, но нужно смотреть код как вы делаете выборку.

Comment: Используете компонент или Bitrix API?

Answer (score 1):

Вот [ссылка](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/content/iblock/components_2/news/news_list.php) на документацию по компоненту news-list. Если вы используете компонент news-list для вывода данных, то порядок их выдачи определяется параметром

```
"SORT_BY1" => "ACTIVE_FROM",
"SORT_ORDER1" => "DESC",
```

на странице вызова компонента. Это гораздо удобней, чем сортировать данные  внутри шаблона